# How do update an item in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#

I have and ObservableCollection but for some reason this code does not work.

```
 private void UpdateChildrenInClass()
    {
        var item = ChildrenInClass.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == CurrentChild.Name);
        if (item != null)
        {
            item = CurrentChild;

        }
    }
```

item displays the currentChild properties but if you look In ChidrenInClass the item properties have not been updated.

Comment: you are just replacint the instance pointed by "item", that doesn't changes nothing on the collection...

Comment: Isn't item now a reference pointing to and item in a Collection? Shouldn't any update to item be reflected in the collection. Maybe i have reference types a bit confused.

Comment: I see the error of my ways, now item is pointing to currentChild not the collection Object! I feel dumb haha

Comment: so, what is `currentChild`, and what is `CurrentChild`?

Comment: @TomKitch Yes, that's right. That's a pretty nicely worded answer (minus the "I feel dumb" -- don't worry about it). You're encouraged to answer your own questions here if you've found the answer; feel free to do so. :)

Comment: @SamIam that was the private and public property names of the collection. I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that item was pointing to the Object in the ObservableCollection that I wanted to update, but I then set item to point to another  object(CurrentChild)